# How to use N indistinguishable dice to simulate 1 roll of N-1 dice?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, dice

If I use 3 indistinguishable dice to simulate 1 roll of 1 die. I can use this formula "(SUM % 6) + 1". There SUM is the total amount of the three indistinguishable dice added together, 6 is the max number givin by a sixsided die and 1 is to output 1-6 instead of 0-5.

How to use N indistinguishable dice to simulate 1 roll of N-1 dice?
Ex. 3 indistinguishable dice to simulate 1 roll of 2 dice.

Source: standupmaths(Matt Parker) "The Three Indistinguishable Dice Puzzle" @ youtube.com

Comment: I take it that the $N-1$ dice are also to be regarded as indistinguishable? (Otherwise this would be impossible for $N\gt3$.)

Comment: Does it mean that you only have the count for each output (1,2,3,4,5,6 ) over the N dice and you need to find a deterministic transformation of those counts to get a count that suit N-1 dice?

Comment: Related: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31101/make-2-dice-out-of-3-dice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt that you'll find a nice solution like the sum for the single die, but I believe it will always be possible to do it by an enumerative mapping (though I don't have a proof for that). Here's the most succinctly describable mapping I came up with to simulate two indistinguishable dice using three:

If the roll is $456$, use $13$. Else, if it's of the form $aaa$, use $66$. Else, if it's of the form $aab$ or $ab1$, use $ab$. Else, order the dice in ascending order to form a $3$-digit number $x$ and find $y=(x+3)\bmod13$. If $y\lt6$, use $yy$, else use $1$ and $y-6$.

[Here's code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/9072c542b7219a349e50f781a4dfbfaf) I used to check that this yields the desired probabilities for two indistinguishable dice.

*P.S.:* On second thought, it's a bit silly to use the $1$ and leave all the higher digits to make the modulo computation more difficult; so here's a version that's slightly easier to carry out by hand. (It's also slightly easier to remember because most of the special numbers are now $6$.)

If the roll is $456$, use $36$. Else, if it's of the form $aaa$, use $16$. Else, if it's of the form $aab$ or $ab6$, use $ab$. Else, order the dice in ascending order, add $1$ to the middle die and let $y$ be the remainder of the resulting $3$-digit number modulo $13$. If $y\lt6$, use $yy$, else use $6$ and $y-6$.

[Here's the corresponding code.](https://gist.github.com/joriki/2106e5625edb53ab4aaf2dac907c6a0e)